# Check td nodeValue with specific class is empty or not

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodevalue

```
    $html = '
    <table class="views-table cols-0 table"><tbody>
<tr class="odd promotionRow views-row-first" style="width:100%;padding:1% !important;margin-right:5px;float:left;">
<td class="weeklyPromotionImage" style="width:110px;vertical-align:top;">
            <a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/yp-weekly/new-newsletter" class="active" style="color:#7abfb5;text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></a><a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/promotion/win-give-your-kid-new-look" style="color:#7abfb5;text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;font-size:14px;"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/sites/default/files/styles/side_bar_image_110x110/public/new-look-110x110.png?itok=jbnpIaIX" width="110" height="110" alt="" style="width:100% !important;height:auto !important;" data-pin-nopin="true"></a>          </td>
                  <td class="weeklyPromotionImage">
                      </td>
                  <td class="weeklyPromotionTitle" style="width:70%;padding-left:5px;">
            <div><a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/promotion/win-give-your-kid-new-look" style="font-size:10px;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;color:#79BAB2;text-decoration:none;">WIN! Give your kid a new look</a></div>
<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;color:#79BAB2;text-decoration:none;">Win it now! For the New Look!!</div>          </td>
              </tr>
<tr class="even promotionRow" style="width:100%;padding:1% !important;margin-right:5px;float:left;">
<td class="weeklyPromotionImage" style="width:110px;vertical-align:top;">
            <a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/yp-weekly/new-newsletter" class="active" style="color:#7abfb5;text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></a><a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/promotion/win-60-cash-voucher-amazonia-singapore" style="color:#7abfb5;text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;font-size:14px;"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/sites/default/files/styles/side_bar_image_110x110/public/110%20X%20110%20Amz.png?itok=31JEV5YU" width="110" height="110" alt="" style="width:100% !important;height:auto !important;" data-pin-nopin="true"></a>          </td>
                  <td class="weeklyPromotionImage" style="width:110px;vertical-align:top;">
                      </td>
                  <td class="weeklyPromotionTitle" style="width:70%;padding-left:5px;">
            <div><a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/promotion/win-60-cash-voucher-amazonia-singapore" style="font-size:10px;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;color:#79BAB2;text-decoration:none;">Win $60 cash voucher from Amazonia Singapore!</a></div>
<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;color:#79BAB2;text-decoration:none;">Win the Cash Voucher from Amazonia Singapore</div>          </td>
              </tr>
<tr class="odd promotionRow views-row-last" style="width:100%;padding:1% !important;margin-right:5px;float:left;">
<td class="weeklyPromotionImage" style="width:110px;vertical-align:top;">
                      </td>
                  <td class="weeklyPromotionImage" style="width:110px;vertical-align:top;">
            <a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/yp-weekly/new-newsletter" class="active" style="color:#7abfb5;text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;font-size:14px;"></a><a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/event/young-parents-primary-1-seminar-2015" style="color:#7abfb5;text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;font-size:14px;"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/sites/default/files/styles/side_bar_image_110x110/public/yp-event-p1.jpg?itok=Jz90Yhwb" width="110" height="110" alt="" style="width:100% !important;height:auto !important;" data-pin-nopin="true"></a>          </td>
                  <td class="weeklyPromotionTitle" style="width:70%;padding-left:5px;">
            <div><a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/event/young-parents-primary-1-seminar-2015" style="font-size:10px;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;color:#79BAB2;text-decoration:none;">Young Parents Primary 1 Seminar 2015</a></div>
<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;color:#79BAB2;text-decoration:none;"></div>
<p style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:1% 0; color:#79BAB2;font-size:20px;"><a href="http://dev-site.youngparents.com.sg/event/young-parents-primary-1-seminar-2015" style="color:#7abfb5;text-decoration:none;font-family:Lato, sans-serif;font-size:14px;">Young Parents Primary 1 Seminar 2015</a></p>          </td>
              </tr>
</tbody></table>
';
```

I want to check td value of class 'weeklyPromotionImage' is empty or not.

I tried the following code. It's just return as empty results. But it's length show is 6.

Please help. I don't know what did I do wrong.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//td[contains(@class,"weeklyPromotionImage")]');

echo "<table>";
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    if ($node->nodeValue=="")
    {
        echo "blank";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($nodes);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output Results

```
object(DOMNodeList)#9 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(6)
}
```

I want to check td value of class 'weeklyPromotionImage'. If it's empty, I want to set it's style to display None.

```
$node->setAttribute('style','display:none;');
```

Comment: what value are you trying to check anyway?

Comment: you have multiple `<td>` elements with class `weeklyPromotionImage`. So, which of them should be empty and which - should not ?

Comment: I want to check value inside the td with class 'weeklyPromotionImage' . E.g

'<td class="weeklyPromotionImage"></td>' this value..

Comment: I want to set attribute to style of td with weeklyPromotionImage with empty value to 'display:none';

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can do is to count the number of children inside that `<td>` tag inside the loop.

But don't include the `DOMText`. A newline character must not be counted.

Idea:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($nodes as $node) {

    // counter
    $count = 0;
    foreach($node->childNodes as $node) {
        // if not a domtext, add count
        if(!($node instanceof \DomText)) $count++;
    }   

    if($count > 0) {
        // no empty node
    } else {
        // is empty
        $node->addAttribute() ... // go on with your code
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @latt sure glad this helped

Comment: @latt: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.